# R dataframe: Time efficient way to transform data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
Val,  Date,   ID
1, 1-JAN-2019, X
2, 2-JAN-2019, X
3, 3-JAN-2019, X
4, 2-JAN-2019, A
5, 3-JAN-2019, A
6, 4-JAN-2019, A
7, 5-JAN-2019, B
```

Which I need to be in the form:

```
   Date,    X,  A,  B
1-JAN-2019, 1, NA, NA
2-JAN-2019, 2,  4, NA
3-JAN-2019, 3,  5, NA
4-JAN-2019, NA, 6, NA
5-JAN-2019, NA, NA, 7
```

I have tried various groupby statements, `df %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% summarise(col = mean(Val))` and can get the desired result using a `for` loop, but I know that `for` loops are not time efficient. I'm looking for some sort of `lapply` type statement that will maximize time efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from example input and output, it's not clear that you need any kind of `summarise`. If that's true of your data in general, it's enough to simply `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Val)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Date              ` X`  ` A`  ` B`
#>   <fct>            <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 "    1-JAN-2019"     1    NA    NA
#> 2 "    2-JAN-2019"     2     4    NA
#> 3 "    3-JAN-2019"     3     5    NA
#> 4 "    4-JAN-2019"    NA     6    NA
#> 5 "    5-JAN-2019"    NA    NA     7
```

I'm using this data, if anyone else wants a go:

```r
txt <- "Val,  Date,       ID
        1,    1-JAN-2019, X
        2,    2-JAN-2019, X
        3,    3-JAN-2019, X
        4,    2-JAN-2019, A
        5,    3-JAN-2019, A
        6,    4-JAN-2019, A
        7,    5-JAN-2019, B"

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One option would be `pivot_wider` after getting the `summarise`d output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID, Date) %>%
    summarise(col = mean(Val)) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = col) %>%
     arrange(dmy(Date))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Date           A     B     X
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1-JAN-2019    NA    NA     1
#2 2-JAN-2019     4    NA     2
#3 3-JAN-2019     5    NA     3
#4 4-JAN-2019     6    NA    NA
#5 5-JAN-2019    NA     7    NA
```

---

Or with `dcast` from `data.table` where we can also specify the `fun.aggregate`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Date ~ ID, value.var = 'Val', mean)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Val = 1:7, Date = c("1-JAN-2019", "2-JAN-2019", 
"3-JAN-2019", "2-JAN-2019", "3-JAN-2019", "4-JAN-2019", "5-JAN-2019"
), ID = c("X", "X", "X", "A", "A", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base` option using `tapply`

```
t(with(df, tapply(Val, list(ID, Date), mean)))

#             A  B  X
# 1-JAN-2019 NA NA  1
# 2-JAN-2019  4 NA  2
# 3-JAN-2019  5 NA  3
# 4-JAN-2019  6 NA NA
# 5-JAN-2019 NA  7 NA
```